# Extract location from URL using strpos

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement, rss, strpos

**How do I extract a location from a url using strpos? If I can't use strpos, then what is a good alternative?**

Here's the URL:

http://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-jobs/ontario/c45l9004

I've tried to use strpos:

```
if (strpos($url,'ontario') !== false){
  echo "yes";
}
```

But it comes up with nothing. On top of this, I need to determine the source of the feed. The breakdown's like this:

1. Determine the source of the RSS Feed (Kijiji)
2. Check for the location in the $url variable (ontario) only if the source is Kijiji.

Here's my code so far:

```
if (strpos($url,'kijiji') !== false){
  if (strpos($url,'ontario') !== false){
    echo "ontario";
  }
}
```

Ideally, Id like this script to check for a location in many different urls, so I can pinpoint the location when displaying a Job Ad.

Comment: `But it comes up with nothing.` --> ?? this `if (strpos($url,'ontario') !== false){` will work

Comment: @FerozAkbar I've tried to run the script as above `if (strpos($url,'ontario') !== false){ echo "yes"; }` However when the page loads "yes" is not visible.

Comment: Can you please give us a more detailed explanation of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parse_url function in order to get all the infgo you need.
See  [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Thank you, I used parse_url to breakdown the url strong, which allowed me to extract the location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your script works for me. Are you sure you have defined $url? Like:

```
$url = 'http://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-jobs/ontario/c45l9004';
if (strpos($url,'ontario') !== false){
    echo "yes";
}
```

And indeed have a look at [url_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, which is for this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

means domain related locality/local jobs

```
$listedDomains["http://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-jobs/%loc%/c45l9004"]  = "ontario";
$listedDomains["http://www.example.com/rss-srp-jobs/%loc%/c45l9004"]= "bangalore";

foreach($listedDomains as $keyUrl=>$keyLocation)
{
    echo str_replace("%loc%",$keyLocation,$keyUrl);
    echo "<br />";
}
```